# Improving my understanding of arc length in relation to 1-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, arc-length

I apologies in advance if this question is so trivial, I had read some textbook on Riemannian geometry and I dont have some things clear. This is the thing: I saw some questions about the arc length showing that it can't be a differential form in the ambient space and I would like to clarify some points. So these are my questions:

Let a regular curve $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then in view of the comments of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4106562/induced-volume-form-to-any-regular-submanifold-of-mathbbrn) using recursively the interior multiplication over the canonical volume form in $\mathbb{R}^n$ I can get an induced volume form $\omega$ in $C$, so

1. What exactly mean the integral of this induced volume form?
2. There is a relation with the arc length $ds$, maybe something like $\|\omega \|_2=ds$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, it’s an oriented volume form. $ds$ is a density associated to an oriented-arclength $1$-form. Just take an adapted orthonormal frame $e_1,\dots,e_n$ along the oriented curve (with $e_1$ tangent and positively oriented), and let $\omega^i$ be the dual coframe. Then $\omega^1$ is the oriented-arclength form and $|\omega^1|=ds$.

Comment: @Ted so, to make things clear, if I have a smooth curve $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^3$ where $N$ and $B$ are the unit normal and unit binormal vector fields to $C=\operatorname{img}(f)$ and define $\omega (v):=dx\wedge dy\wedge dz(N,B,v)$ for $v\in T\Bbb R^3$ then $\omega $ is a volume form in $C$, then I will have $$\int_0^{1}|f'(t)|dt=\int_{C}|\omega |$$ ??

Comment: Yes, and you can remove the absolute value if you orient $C$ as a $1$-dimensional manifold (with boundary) by the parametrization $f$.